# gulp-sftp with AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, gulp, sftp

I am using gulp for my node.js project. I have an AWS ubuntu server where I want to copy some files using gulp.

I am using the following code in gulp

```
const sftp = require('gulp-sftp');

gulp.task('deploy', () => {
return gulp.src('deploy/bundle.zip')
          .pipe(sftp({
            host: 'ec2-x-x-x-x.us-x.compute.amazonaws.com',
            key: { 
              location: '~/mykey.pem'
            }
          }));
});
```

However, I am getting the following error when I run gulp-deploy

```
[18:07:29] Using gulpfile ~/src/gulpfile.js
[18:07:29] Starting 'deploy'...
[18:07:29] Authenticating with private key.
[18:07:33] 'deploy' errored after 3.45 s
[18:07:33] Error in plugin 'gulp-sftp'
Message:
    Authentication failure. Available authentication methods: publickey
Details:
    level: authentication
    partial: false
[18:07:33] gulp-sftp SFTP abrupt closure
[18:07:33] Connection :: close
```

I don't understand how to proceed further to troubleshoot. Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing *user* as part of your options. It should either be *root* or *ubuntu* if you're linux or ubuntu, respectively.

Also for gulp-sftp, "Authentication failure. Available authentication methods: publickey" is a catch-all error even if your key location is invalid (in my case, it was). So make sure your path is correct as well.

My code:

```
.pipe(sftp({
    host: 'serverurl.com',
    user: 'ubuntu',
    key: 'D:/path/to/key.pem'
}))
```